# Wrong connection string when try to connect in a replica set standalone mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, replicaset

I'm trying to create a mongo server just for testing transactions, for that I have to create a replica set.

I convert standalone mongodb to replicaset via docker-compose:

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: test-mongodb
    command: '--storageEngine wiredTiger --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all --noauth'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: testdb
      MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME: rs0
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate().ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s
```

rs.status()

```
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2021-02-24T15:07:43.708Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 1,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 1,
    "votingMembersCount" : 1,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 1,
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1614179254, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-02-24T15:07:34.381Z"),
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1614179254, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2021-02-24T15:07:34.381Z"),
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1614179254, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1614179254, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-02-24T15:07:34.381Z"),
        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2021-02-24T15:07:34.381Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1614179214, 1),
    "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
        "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
        "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2021-02-24T14:58:54.274Z"),
        "electionTerm" : NumberLong(1),
        "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1614178734, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "numVotesNeeded" : 1,
        "priorityAtElection" : 1,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
        "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2021-02-24T14:58:54.328Z"),
        "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2021-02-24T14:58:54.411Z")
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "ce74cad70774:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 540,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1614179254, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-02-24T15:07:34Z"),
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1614178734, 2),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-02-24T14:58:54Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 1,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1614179254, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1614179254, 1)
}
```

When i try to connect via connection string:
`mongo --host mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0`

receive the error:

```
Error: connect failed to replica set rs0/localhost:27017
```

Can I do this using only 1 default node?

What would be the valid connection string for me to connect to the master?

Comment: That error message does not specify the failure reason. Either get that reason out of the software you are using or use different software (e.g. mongo shell).

Comment: Your replica set has only one member, so there are not many other options.

Comment: rs.initiate() runs only once, I don't think it is useful for a health check.